# Aframe detecting when visibility is changed within a component

Tags: aframe

How can I detect when the visibility of an entity changes within a component? I'm writing a video player component, and I need the video player to remove its own clickable class when it's not visible, to avoid being able to click on an invisible element.

Right now I'm thinking about using the `componentchanged` event on the video player to listen to changes in the visibility component.

Comment: Share your complete runnable attempt with https://glitch.com/~aframe or it will be hard to help. best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `componentchanged` and listened for when the visible component changes.

Ex.

```js
    this.el.addEventListener('componentchanged', (e) => {
      if (e.detail.name === 'visible') this.updateClickable();
    });
```